# Issue with UIView on IPhone 7plus and 8plus

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

UIView on IPhone plus stretched and normal on regular sized iPhone. Constraints are all done in story board. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong. Please help. Attached are imaged of the views : iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone 7.

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: attach a screenshot of constraints

Comment: @Sh_Khan, see edits above with screenshot of the constraints. Thanks for your help!

Comment: see answer.......

Answer (score 0):

I figured my issue was with my misunderstanding of auto layout, which is why I was not able to get my uiview to adjust properly across different screen sizes. This tutorial on youtube really broke down auto layout in such a simple way. Check it out (link below). I hope it helps someone else out there. thanks!

["Auto Layout Tutorial in Xcode with Swift for iOS 11 | iOS Development Tutorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=synofzEkUfU)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the bottom constraint because of different screen heights you get different height for the view as the bottom constraint is static (528) , so to fix that remove that constraint and give it a static height or proportional to screen height

Also remove one of the top constraints as setting 1 is enough